# Core Data got empty results in WAL journal_mode after app launch in iOS7, data lost

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

My app is using Core Data framework with storage type of sqlite . I received several feedback commenting that user data stored in Core Data is lost, it seems the sqlite file read fail. After i got the sqlite files from user, there are 3 files (.sqlite, .sqlite-wal, .sqlite-shm).
But only empty results can be queried in these sqlite files. 
What I got from the users is they may power off their iPhone while the app is active.

I just noticed Core Data begin use WAL as the default journal_mode in ios7, while it's default as DELETE prior to ios7. I didn't set up the journal_mode manually in my code.

I'm not sure what is the root cause of this issue. But data lost is unacceptable to users anyway. Did anyone happen to meet this issue before?

Should I set up the journal_mode to DELETE manually for all iOS version?
Thank you!

**Update：**
User reported it works normally on previous day, but then everything is lost on next day.

Comment: I would, there seem to be many issues with WAL mode.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? @user3096098